# Slow response-time cheat sheet

Tags: usability, response-time

Does anyone have links to current and historical papers and authoritative links (statistics and blog posts) regarding response-time for user interfaces?

Naturally the authoritative link is [Human factors design criteria in man-computer interaction](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=810380)

Some key quotes include:

> [Regarding] response to request for
>   next page. […] Delays of longer than 1
>   second will seem intrusive on the
>   continuity of thought.

And

> Assume an inquiry of any kind has been
>   made. The user – and his attention –
>   is captive to the terminal until he
>   receives a response. If he is a busy
>   man, captivity of more than 15
>   seconds, even for information
>   essential to him, may be more than an
>   annoyance and disruption. It can
>   readily become a demoralizer – that is
>   a, reducer of work pace and of
>   motivation to work.

These quotes are 40 years old, yet so relevant today.

There is also Jacob Nielsen's [authoritative excerpt](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html).

I would like to collect all the links to this kind of research under this community wiki.

Next time you are told to ignore response times by your manager or build a feature that will slow down your application you can simply send them a link to this page.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest answer was in an article by Jakob Nielsen where he defined the 10/1/.1 second rule in [Response Times: The Three Important Limits](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html). That article is based on a section from his book [Usability Engineering](http://www.useit.com/jakob/useengbook.html). He's presenting further research and applicability to the web in several 2009 sessions, all linked to from [1](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Jared Spool shares some results of research conducted at UIE about the [importance of performing a goal rather than download time](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2006/02/14/uietips-06-02-14/).

> Since we conducted the original
>   research five years ago, we’ve
>   repeatedly discovered users are more
>   interested in achieving their goals
>   than having speedy page loads. Since
>   goals are often complex and require
>   the users to be thoughtful, the best
>   designed sites seem to get away with
>   slower-than-average pages.

The original research from 2001 he references is [The Truth About Download Time](http://www.uie.com/events/roadshow/articles/download_time/) by Christine Perfetti and Lori Landesman.

Comment: That being said, response time is important. Just be sure that your user's needs are met foremost.

Comment: If your pages are taking 15 seconds to load "It can readily become a demoralizer". People were a little more forgiving in the earlier days of the web when everything was slow. I think slow response-time is the first problem that needs to be tackled ... its certainly not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across:

*[System Response Time and User Satisfaction: An Experimental Study of Browser-based Application](http://www.collecter.org/archives/2000_April/03.pdf)* (watch out its a PDF) by John A. Hoxmeier, Ph.D.

The summary of the findings are:

- H1 satisfaction decreases as response time increases [**supported**]
- H2 Dissatisfaction leads to discontinued use [**supported**]
- H3 ease of use decreases as satisfaction decreases [**supported**]
- H4 experienced users more tolerant of slower response times [**not supported**]

Answer (score 1):

**Saving Lives**

I read this [little article](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Saving_Lives.txt)

To quote Steve Jobs:

> "Well, let's say you can shave 10
>   seconds off of the boot time. Multiply
>   that by five million users and thats
>   50 million seconds, every single day.
>   Over a year, that's probably dozens of
>   lifetimes. So if you make it boot ten
>   seconds faster, you've saved a dozen
>   lives. That's really worth it, don't
>   you think?"

I think the same argument can be made for response-time on high volume sites.

Comment: After reading the quote from Stevie I kinda felt sad for him.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the link lavinio posted, Jakob Nielsen's recent article outlines a 0.5/0.1/0.5 second rule for hover times of dropdown menus.

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mega-dropdown-menus.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across these recently pertaining to website speed:

Men Need Speed
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/usability-criteria/

Study: Web Users Prefer Speed Over Customization
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/design-factors/